# sound_play consumes high CPU and makes strange voice after some moment

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I totally  modified the original question description that wasn't clear.**

With `sound_play`, CPU load sometimes reaches 10+ with some of my codes, and sound eventually gets messy and hard to hear.

I found in Ubuntu's Sound Preference panel that `sound_play/soundplay_node.py` instance keeps populating like in the image below. Sometimes calling `stopAll()` function decreases the instance, sometimes not. In my understanding, `sound_play/soundplay_node.py` makes a new instance every time it receives `/robosound` topic. So instanciating itself is not bad but what's bad is the instance doesn't get removed.

I haven't figured out the condition where I reproduce the phenomenon. [This python code](http://pastebin.com/pLBv710K) I made for debug, which publishes `/robosound` only regularly with decent amount of sleep after publishing, works well. However, another code of mine that publishes topics irregularly causes an issue above.

I frequently see the following error on the terminal `soundplay_node.py` runs. But I can't specify when it occurs, even after I briefly looked at [`soundplay_node.py`](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/sound_play/html/soundplay__node_8py_source.html):

```
[ERROR] Exception in cleanupdict for sound (%SPOKEN_TEXT%): query failed
```

Iterative command from commandine like the following doesn't causes the issue until the end.

```
for i in {0..100} ; do rosrun sound_play say.py 'You got pudding ' ; done
```

Changing voice types on `festival` doesn't make any change in terms of this issue.

Because I see the same phenomenon using both .cpp and .py and topic contents are the same, I suspect there's something in how `sound_play` handles the topics when the interval is irregular/too short, particularly in `soundplay_node.py`. But I haven't been successful hacking.

Environment-1: Ubuntu 11.04 `electric`

Environment-2: Ubuntu 10.04 `electric` (`Turtlebot eeepc`)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12246/sound_play-consumes-high-cpu-and-makes-strange-voice-after-some-moment/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-10**:
Self comment; because no workaround was found and hacking was hard, we decided not to use sound_play and use festival directly from python (of which codes was made in an hour...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticket is now opened. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5293

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0